How do I use idx environment to add the Google application credentials?
I m trying to use idx environment with Google vision cloud. This is my code:
import idx

# Set the environment variable using idx.set_env()
idx.set_env("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS", "test/stuffie-projet-cce8b453d29c.json")
def detect_text(path):
    """Detects text in the file."""
    from google.cloud import vision

    client = vision.Client(project='stuffietestapi', credentials=
                           {
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "stuffie-projet",
  "private_key_id": "cce8b453d29c2080c7c44d27e87a9bdeb10b2d3e",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----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\nAPAc6dc0e3AiSsNxDv0++eM=\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "stuffietestapi@stuffie-projet.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": "103668130499698990264",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/stuffietestapi%40stuffie-projet.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "universe_domain": "googleapis.com"
}
                           )
    with open(path, "rb") as image_file:
        content = image_file.read()

    image = vision.Image(content=content)

    response = client.text_detection(image=image)
    texts = response.text_annotations
    print("Texts:")

    for text in texts:
        print(f'\n"{text.description}"')

        vertices = [
            f"({vertex.x},{vertex.y})" for vertex in text.bounding_poly.vertices
        ]

        print("bounds: {}".format(",".join(vertices)))

    if response.error.message:
        raise Exception(
            "{}\nFor more info on error messages, check: "
            "https://cloud.google.com/apis/design/errors".format(response.error.message)
        )
        
print(detect_text(path="test/yassir.png"))


I know it is working with os, but I'm trying to run it in idx google.
I tried os but it doesn't work because I don't have the access to os. I'm using just google idx environment.

I highly recommend you change all sensitive information in your post to dummy values for security and privacy.
